# Is a visa needed for a stop over in Canada

Tags: visas, canada, uk-citizens

I'm a UK national passport holder living in Peru, do I need a Canadian visa for a 3/4 hour stop over to connect to a UK flight?

Comment: 45 minutes isn't remotely enough time to connect between two international flights (or, really, any two flights). If that's on one ticket, I'm amazed they sold it to you; if it's on two separate tickets, the second airline will have no liability to you when you miss the connection.

Comment: Oh, wait. By "3/4 hour", do you mean "three-quarters of an hour" or "three or four hours"?

Answer (score 1):

Canada doesn't do "sterile transit". So if you have a stopover there you will need to enter the country.

If you are a British Citizen then you can normally enter Canada without a visa. However Canada are in the process of introducing an eTA system (similar to the US ESTA system). From what I can see online they are currently in a "leniency period" where you are supposed to get an eTA but it is not strictly enforced. As with the US ESTA the Canadian eTA is not a visa per-se but it is something you need to get in advance before travelling if you are arriving by air.

If you have one of the more unusual types of British nationality then go look things up yourself on http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp some types require a visa.

Comment: -1, not only certain nationals should look up whether they need a visa. Being British (or whatever) does not imply in absolutely all cases a visafree, stressfree entry. Everybody traveling to Canada should check the eTA.

Answer (score 1):

Check at the official Canadian eTA page at: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/eta.asp whether you need a visa and how to apply through eTA. All foreigner travelers either need a visa or need to apply through eTA as a visa-exempt foreign national. Exceptions include U.S. citizens, and travellers with a valid Canadian visa. Until fall 2016 you can board your flight without filling the eTA, but it takes just a couple of minutes to fill it, and you get an answer within minutes too. So, why not do it?

Notice that being British does not imply automatically that you do not need a visa.

Comment: This isn't quite the whole story.  There are some foreign nationals who qualify for transit without visa; these people do not need eTA.  See http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp, http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp, and http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/visa/china.asp.  The first also lists several uncommon cases where eTA is not needed, such as diplomats, flight crews, aviation inspectors, accident investigators, and the Queen of Canada and members of the royal family.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are more exceptions than I have listed. I hope that the if the Queen was reading my lines I did make her waste her time applying for a visa or eTA.